# Make a Shell script calling Perl scripts executable in windows

Tags: perl, shell, exe

My question is I have folder containing 3 scripts(perlx2 and shellx1) and an internal folder of data that I wish to use in the perl scripts.

The shell script calls the two perl scripts consecutively the first one creating a file and the second one performing an analysis of the data from the created file.

From reading I could use Active perl or something of the sort to package the Perls scripts to be executable for a basic windows user. However I think it would make more sense if I made a sort of Batch file that will run the whole set of programs.

Sorry about my lack of knowledge I would love some help with this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Running `perl` scripts from a `.bat` in Windows

**Installation & Configuration of `perl`**

First, install `perl` (I prefer [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) but ActivePerl will work too).

This should put `perl` in your path, to check open up a command line and type:

`echo %PATH%`

You should see `C:\strawberry\perl\bin` in there (`perl` is in that directory).

**Adding `perl` to your path (skip if already present)**

Navigate Start -> Settings -> Control Panel -> System -> Advanced -> Environment Variables. Choose `Path` and append the following to the variable:

`;C:\strawberry\c\bin;C:\strawberry\perl\bin`

Close your command shell and open a new one. Retry `echo %PATH%`.

**Assuming `perl` is in your path now...**

Make a file called `perlscripts.bat` and type the following:

```
perl c:\path\to\scripts\script1.pl
perl c:\path\to\scripts\script2.pl
```

Running this batch should run the scripts in order as desired.

Answer (score 0):

> > The shell script calls the two perl scripts consecutively the first one creating a file and the second one performing an analysis of the data from the created file.

You can directly call those perl scripts from perl itself, it will work in both windows& linux, why shell/batch, why need bother every time for different OS.
like, `<script to run>`